# Wildfly 8.0.0Final: Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Initial state transfer timed out for cache

Tags: java, caching, jboss, infinispan, wildfly

Need some direction with this, we have a 2 server in standalone-full-ha with infinispan ejb caching [the standard configuration standalone-full-ha.xml]. All was fine till today, when one of the server after application [war] deployment has issues stating " Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Initial state transfer timed out for cache".

A look at the directory data/infinispan shows that at begin it starts to sync up the cache from the other server but times out and that is clear as the disk-size of data/infinispan/ejb are different on both servers..... looks like some timeout is kicking in .. can someone kindly give me inputs regarding this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it a programming question, or an administration question? If the latter, it's better off on Super User.

Comment: Hard to say what's causing it, any other errors in the other cluster nodes? If you can reproduce it easily, enable TRACE on `org.infinispan` package and get thread dumps when the error is produced on the server showing the issue and other nodes.

Comment: Is this issue fixed?